# Make a grid of divs floated right with parent table div the size of its children

Tags: html, css

This is my failed attempt:

> https://jsfiddle.net/j75hxxa2/1/

I want the block on the right side and the extra gray part gone.

Adding

```
float: right;
```

To the parent makes its children very small and tiny. If I try to widen the children by adding

```
width: 50%;
```

They break the line.

Is there a simple fix?

(Also I think

```
margin-top: 1px;
```

Isn't working?)

Thanks in advance

Comment: why not just use a table? I don't really understand what you are trying to do here?

Comment: @markt I tried using tables, but I couldn't make that work properly. Seems I'm not too good with divs either...

Comment: From your fiddle, it looks like you are trying to produce tabular data - in which case a table is the semantically correct tag to use. What was your problem with the table?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/j75hxxa2/19/ - key part of code: `content: ""; display: block; clear:both;` at the end of the table in `::after` (pseudo element). Also see http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way is to use a table:

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr><td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td>Text</td></tr>
  <tr><td>I</td><td>II</td><td>III</td><td>IIII</td></tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    background: #000;
    border-top: 1px solid #777;
    border-left: 1px solid #777;
}

table tr td {
    border-right: 1px solid #777;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #777;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: I added this to the table:
 "table-layout: fixed;"
to ensure the same width

Answer (score 1):

Add float left to .cell as below, I have changed background color, change it back to your previously assigned or as you wish.

```
.cell {
  width: 24.8%;
  float:left;
}
#table {
margin-right: 1px;
margin-top: 1px;
background-color: #f22;
width:100%;
height:37px;
}
```

Comment: unfortunately the background disappears